# How to create a underlined hyperlink in RML (z3c.rml)

Tags: rml

I want to create underlined hyperlink in a PDF.

I use `z3c.rml` to create the PDF.

This creates a working hyperlink:

```
<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
```

But to make it more obvious for the reader that this is a hyperlink I would like to underline it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<u><a href="http://example.com">example.com</a></u>
```